# Preventing newly added column to become last in order

Tags: azure-data-explorer

Is it possible to add a new column to an existing Kusto table somewhere in the middle , I don't want it to become last column in the table. Right now when I am issuing `.create-merge table` command on an existing table and no matter which order I specify for the new column, it always ends up becoming last column in the table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are right and it is also written in the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/management/create-merge-table-command):

[image]

If the motivation to re-order the column is in query scenarios, you can create a function (view) with the same name of the table that [re-order](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/projectreorderoperator) the columns as you like, this will allow existing queries to work uninterrupted and the column order to be adjusted.

If the motivation is the ingestion scenario where column order is significant (such as in CSV ingestion or update policy), the new column should be specified at the end, no way around it.